# <a onclick="one4()" href="Calculator.html">2.2</a> one4() function is not working when I go to the Calculator.html file... please help me out

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">Semester </a>
        <a  onclick="one1(),one()" >1.1</a>
        <a onclick="one2(),two()"  >1.2</a>
        <a onclick="one3()">2.1</a>
        <a onclick="one4()" href="Calculator.html">2.2</a>
        <a onclick="one5()" href="Calculator.html">3.1</a>
        <a onclick="one6()" href="Calculator.html">3.2</a>
        <a onclick="one7()" href="Calculator.html">4.1</a>
        <a onclick="one8()" href="Calculator.html">4.2</a>
      </div>
```

one4() function is not working when I go to the Calculator.html file...I have tried several times but I have no idea what's going on.. I am a beginner in this sector.

here is my javascript code

```
function one4() 
{ 
console.log("hello"); //this function is not called
}
```

---

---

Comment: Please create [mcve]

Comment: function one4()  will be triggered but then you'll get redirected to Calculator.html you'll loose the console log. enable preserve logs option

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is or how it's "not working", but it's working as supposed to.

The `one4()` triggers just fine, but it also opens new page which ultimately cancels everything else and clears developers console.

Here is a demonstration with 2sec delay before it redirects:

```js
function one4() {
  console.log("hello"); //this function is not called
  let link = event.target;
  event.preventDefault(); //cancel redirect to Calculator.html
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    link.onclick = null; //remove onclick trigger
    link.click(); //trigger redirect
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">Semester </a>
  <a onclick="one1(),one()">1.1</a>
  <a onclick="one2(),two()">1.2</a>
  <a onclick="one3()">2.1</a>
  <a onclick="one4()" href="Calculator.html">2.2</a>
  <a onclick="one5()" href="Calculator.html">3.1</a>
  <a onclick="one6()" href="Calculator.html">3.2</a>
  <a onclick="one7()" href="Calculator.html">4.1</a>
  <a onclick="one8()" href="Calculator.html">4.2</a>
</div>
```